# Javascript - Grouping function with reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping, reduce

Can someone explains step by step the following function? I lost it when the body of the reduce begins:

```
let people = [
  { name: 'Alice', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 20 }
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    let key = obj[property]
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push(obj)
    return acc
  }, {})
}

let groupedPeople = groupBy(people, 'age')
```

Comment: how about putting console.log everywhere and tracking what the code does?

Comment: @grodzi - Or, rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, he could *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into his IDE or browser.

Comment: @grodzi I've done it, but can't get the logic...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder , thank you sir for your answer. If you want it you can answer my question with the solution you already provided, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` makes that function more complex-seeming than it actually is. (`reduce` is hugely overused, and almost always the wrong tool vs. a simple loop *unless* you're doing [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) with predefined, reusable reducer functions.) Here's the same function without the unnecessary `reduce`, with explanation:

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  // The object we'll return with properties for the groups
  let result = {}
  // Loop through the array
  for (const obj of objectArray) {
    // Get the key value
    let key = obj[property]
    // If the result doesn't have an entry for that yet, create one
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = []
    }
    // Add this entry to that entry
    result[key].push(obj)
  }
  // Return the grouped result
  return result
}
```

The `reduce` version just passes `result` around (as `acc`): `reduce` calls the callback with the initial value (the `{}` you see near the end of the `reduce` call) and the first entry, which the callback receives as `acc` and `obj`. Then the callback does one entry's work and returns `acc`, which means it receives it again on the next pass.